# Как при нажатии на кнопку сделать так, что бы не было видно контейнер?

Tags: c#, winforms

У меня есть кнопка, которая отвечает за видимость контейнера, то есть когда я нажимаю на кнопку, контейнер становится видимым, но что нужно дописать в код, что бы при повторном нажатии, контейнер снова становился невидимым? (winforms C#)

Comment: Выложите код, чтобы дать вам ответ.

Answer (score 0):

Вот пример как :
кнопка показывает и скрывает texbox1

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (textBox1.Visible)
        {
            textBox1.Visible = false;
        }
        else
        {
            textBox1.Visible = true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: СПАСИБО ТЕБЕ БОЛЬШОЕ ЧУВАК))))

Comment: Можно проще: `textBox1.Visible = !textBox1.Visible` :)